# Windows Phone App working also on Windows 8 desktop

Tags: windows-8, win-universal-app

I have Windows Phone App, and i want install this App also on my pc. 
How i can make with this Windows Phone Application, Windows Universal App working on mobile phone and desktop pc?

Comment: Please add more info on your Windows Phone App - is it an 8.1 / WinRT or is it Silverlight?

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you google "Porting Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight to Windows Store app WinRT", study the first few links and their sublinks, then feel free to rephrase your question, when you get stuck at something specific - will be happy to answer.